# How can you "construct" a high pressure?

Tags: experimental-physics, pressure

To create high pressure you have to enclose material in another material. Does this mean that the force involved in the pressure you want to create can never be higher than the binding forces which hold the constituents of the enclosing material together?

Comment: Stars exist and they aren't enclosed by anything.

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't have plans for entering a star! I'm talking about people creating pressure. In plain English. From the verb "to create" (dead matter like a star doesn't create). I don't ask if pressure exists without an enclosing material. I could go out in the air to experience that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. But note however that most common materials yield and fail at stress levels far, far below that represented by the strength of the binding forces between their constituent atoms. This is because of defects in their crystalline structure which allow the material to bend and distort i.e., they contain *deformation mechanisms* that reduce their strength.

This means that pressure vessels require walls that are far thicker than you would expect in the absence of deformation mechanisms.